# How to assign user+group-specific roles in Laravel 4 with Entrust

Tags: database, laravel, permissions, eloquent, roles

Background: One user can be in zero, one, or many departments.

I am trying to setup roles and permissions in my application using the [Entrust package by Zizaco](https://github.com/Zizaco/entrust/tree/1.0). It seems fairly straightforward, however my use-case is slightly different than what it offers out-of-the-box, if I am understanding it correctly, as it is supposed to attach a role to a user.

In my case, a user can have a different role in a different department. For example, a user John in Department A could be an administrator, while John in Department B is only a reviewer. If I use Entrust as-is then John would have both Administrator and Reviewer in both departments that he belongs to.

I have tried creating a pivot table between User and Department and then modifying Entrust to work off the 'id' in the department_user table, however I cannot get that to work correctly when I try to do something simple like the following to create a table to show what user in the department has what role:

```
$department = Department::find(1);
$users = $department->users;
```

Is there a way I can modify Entrust to work like this? Or is there a better package for this type of use-case? Roles are the same across all departments and for the sake of efficiency I would like to avoid creating department-specific roles (like Accounting Administrator, Biology Administrator, etc.)